# CSS3 Gradient Background working in Chrome and Firefox but not IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gradient

I currently am trying to use a linear-gradient from CSS3 as the background of a site, and from what I can tell, am following the spec to comply with Internet Explorer right, but I can't tell what's not working here.

```
body {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
background: rgb(0,0,0); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(26,42,132,1) 40%, rgba(33,29,155,1) 50%, rgba(26,42,132,1) 60%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(26,42,132,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(33,29,155,1)), color-stop(60%,rgba(26,42,132,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(26,42,132,1) 40%,rgba(33,29,155,1) 50%,rgba(26,42,132,1) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(26,42,132,1) 40%,rgba(33,29,155,1) 50%,rgba(26,42,132,1) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(26,42,132,1) 40%,rgba(33,29,155,1) 50%,rgba(26,42,132,1) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(26,42,132,1) 40%,rgba(33,29,155,1) 50%,rgba(26,42,132,1) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using following CSS in one of our projects and it works on Chrome, Firefox and IE11.

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#000), to(transparent));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, transparent);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#000, transparent);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#000, transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(#000, transparent);
```

See this Fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/3ck72fbc/

Comment: BTW, I tested your code in IE11 and it is working at my side.

Comment: Thanks, I had a friend access it on IE11 and it seemed to be working fine, so the problem must lie on my end, which I could care less if IE doesn't work on my comp, lol.